# Why is $|g'(z)| < 1 $ a condition for convergence?

Tags: numerical-methods, convergence-divergence

For example this function (its zero is  $z \approx 0.5$) -

$$f(x) =  \displaystyle x+\ln{x} $$ 
and the iterative formula  -

$$ \displaystyle x_{n+1} = -\ln{x_n} $$

So iterative formula is  $g(x) =  \displaystyle -\ln{x} $  and $g'(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$     .

Why does the fact that $|g'(z)| \approx 2 >1$  provides that this iterative formula doesn't convergence  ?

Comment: You forgot absolute values: $|g'(z)|\approx 2$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: fixed

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Mean value theorem.

If $x_m$ and $x_n$ are close, then:

$$x_{m+1}-x_{n+1} = g(x_m)-g(x_n) = g'(z_0)(x_m-x_n)$$

for some $z_0$ between $x_m$ and $x_n$.

If $x_m$ and $x_n$ are close to $z$ then $z_0$ is close to $z$ and therefore $x_{m+1}$ and $x_{n+1}$ are further apart than $x_m$ and $x_n$ were.

Comment: So you hint that $g'(z_0)$ describe the relation of this further ?